Knowledge base sharing library file error
I have a problem when sharing a file from the library via knowledge base. I will explain the whole process and what the problem is. When sharing an article, Autolaunched flow is launched, which checks whether there is a Collaborator Group (a private group to which management board members belong), if so, we check whether there is a Content Document Link between the file (attached to the article) and this group, if not, we create such connection. Everything works fine until the file is in the library. We are trying to share this file with ShareType 'C' because we want group members to be able to edit these files. I looked in many places and tried many settings such as: "Deliver Content" in Salesforce Classic, "Content Deliveries and Public Links can be enabled to let communities users share files managed by libraries" etc. Is it possible to meet these requirements? I saw in the documentation that you can only create a Content Document Link with type "V", so maybe there's a workaround for that?
Below is a screenshot with an error in flow
Thank you in advance for your answer
